# How to download finished Wordpress project from Google Cloud?

Tags: google, cloud

I created a WP website with hosting on Google Cloud just like an IP address.
I already have an old website, which I now want to delete and replace by this new one.
I would like to ask you, how can I download this project from Cloud to my computer, so I can later upload it on the server of the old website?
Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Never built a site on Google cloud but basically you'll need to export the database SQL, then download the entire `/wp-content/` directory.  Then, put WordPress on your hosting, upload your `/wp-content/` directory, import your SQL into the database for the WordPress site and run a search/replace on the database changing the IP address to the URL of your site.

Answer (score 0):

When you are migrating the wp site you have to download the wp-content folder, and the database, and you have to replace the links in the database. you can then istall a fresh version of wp in the new location and replace the wp-content folder and the modifyed database, howewer, some errors may occure, ore settings may be lost fore some plugins. An easier way is to use a wp-migration plugin.